# Change dash in reference list (biblatex-gost)

Tags: biblatex

I use `biblatex-gost` to format the reference list. But the output uses a long dash. How do I replace the long dash with a normal dash?

My `biblatex` options:

```
\usepackage[
citestyle=gost-numeric,
bibstyle=gost-numeric,
]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the pre-set option `blockpunct=emdash,` `biblatex-gost` sets

```
\renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\addperiod\addnbspace\textemdash\space\bibsentence}
```

If you want an en dash and no em dash, simple change `\textemdash` to `\textendash`.

Additionally the Russian language module sets `\bibrangedash` to an em dash, so you may want to change that as well.

```
\documentclass[russian]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newblockpunct}{\addperiod\addnbspace\textendash\space\bibsentence}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{russian}{%
  \protected\def\bibrangedash{%
    \textendash\penalty\hyphenpenalty}% breakable dash
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Nussbaum M. Aristotle’s «De Motu Animalium». – Princeton : Princeton University Press, 1978." with en-dash and not em-dash.]